# Поиск всех возможных путей в графе, питон

Tags: python, graph

Добрый день, требуется код на питоне (3+), имеем граф, данные вводятся построчно как ребра, потом метки вершин. пример:
(первое число - 8 - кол-во вершин, второе - 12 - кол-во ребер)

```
8 12
0 1
0 5
1 5
1 4
5 4
5 6
1 2
4 2
4 6
2 6
2 3
7 6
0 L
4 L
2 L
3 L
1 W
5 W
7 W
6 W

8
```

Требуется найти все возможные пути, такие что W-L-W-L или L-W-L-W
путь считается разным, если хотя бы одна вершина в пути отличается по номеру.
(Последняя цифра - 8 - количество таких путей в приведенном примере).
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Здесь не решают задачи за других людей, только помогают с конкретными вопросами.

Comment: Прошу прощения, я не это имел в виду. Вопрос следующий - я распарсил ввод в словарь, ключ - вершина, значение - список ребер и маркировка вершины. `{'0': '1 2 3 W', '2': '0 4 5 L', '4': '1 2 3 W', '3': '0 4 5 L', '1': '0 4 5 L', '5': '1 2 3 W'}` для примера. Как можно было бы удобнее найти пути?